# How to copy a complicated ViewGroup to a bitmap?

Tags: java, android

Can not make a bitmap from a complicated view with state machine.

I have a RelativeLayout in which a dynamic tree of views handles touchevents to draw graphics. It uses a state machine to keep track of events like down, move and up and perform various drawing activities.

Now I want to make a copy (bitmap) of this RelativeLayout every time the view changes and display on the second screen. I have tried both methods I found online:

1. draw(theSecondCanvas);
2. Bitmap cache = getDrawingCache();

Both work most of time except occasional failure. The problem is both methods will eventually call every child views' draw() one more time to draw on the second canvas. But the state machine has changed to the different state based on the last touch event. It gives different drawing result or sometime error with null object reference because the additional drawing request has no touch event associated with it.

One option is for me to fix the complicated logic of state machine in the tree of views so it can handle an additional stateless drawing on the second canvas.

But I would think it has to be a simpler way to capture a bitmap from a view without drawing everything again. The view has done all the drawing inside already. It doesn't make sense to repeat the same work on the second canvas just to get a copy of bitmap.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "The view has done all the drawing inside already" -- yes, but not to a bitmap. The "drawing" is being handled by GPU operations on modern devices.

Comment: MiraCast can copy the full screen from frame buffer. I am wondering if a renderscript  can capture the rendered view before GPU merges it with other buffers. ...

Comment: "MiraCast can copy the full screen from frame buffer" -- that is implemented at the firmware level, not the app level. "I am wondering if a renderscript can capture the rendered view before GPU merges it with other buffers" -- I am not aware that it can, though I am *far* from being a RenderScript expert.

Comment: I tried a different approach. I move the complicated layout offscreen. Then only render it to a canvas/bitmap that I created. Then render this bitmap to a SurfaceView to replace the original view and render this same bitmap to the second SurfaceView to be a mirror. Therefore, the complicated layout with state machine is only rendered once. so I can avoid the mismatched state problem.

Comment: However, here comes the complication. When I dispatch the touch events from the on-screen view to this off-screen complicated layout, I realized that the offscreen view handles the touch events in different manner. For example, Webview inside of offscreen layout gives the error that it can't scroll the page when the layout is not attached to a window. It is more complicated than I thought.                        "ZoomButtonsController: Cannot make the zoom controller visible if the owner view is not attached to a window."

Answer (score 0):

I realized that off-screen rendering is not necessary in my case. I can intercept default canvas and draw on my own canvas with a bitmap. Then copy the bitmap to the default canvas. This solves the problem.